# Are there any active IRC channels for RCE discussion?

Tags: disassembly

I enjoy idling in programming related IRC channels so I can research any topic which catches my interest.  I have checked the channels for a few forums that I browse, but I can't seem to find an active community.  What are some active RCE related channels?  It can be about malware analysis / tools / general help / etc, anything.

Hopefully this is on topic.  I can't think of anywhere else to ask.

Comment: ##re on freenode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Freenode check out:

"##re"

"##asm"

"#radare"

Answer (score 2):

[#cracking4newbies](http://woodmann.com/krobar/beginner/221.html) on [EFnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFnet)​​​​​